# Why is my print function giving the wrong output in my program to print strings?

Tags: c

The expected outcome is for example:

```
a
word
a sentence
```

This is the outcome tho:

```
 aword
word
a sentence
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    char letter[1], word[20], sentence[100];  
    
    scanf("%s", letter);
    
    scanf("%s", word);
    
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", sentence);
    
    printf("\n %s", letter);
    printf("\n %s", word);
    printf("\n %s", sentence);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please only tag C and C++ when the question is about interoperation between the two languages. Do you compile this code as C or as C++ ?

Comment: The format `%[^\n]` isn't a subset of the format `%s` and it is usually incorrect to have `scanf(" %[^\n]s", sentence);`. Try `scanf(" %[^\n]", sentence);`

Comment: `char letter[1]` can hole **one** character. Since a C string requires a terminating nullchar tha must be accounted for in storage, that means that array can hold a string of exactly *no* characters and one terminator. E.g. an empty. Your code invokes undefined behavior on the first `scanf` by breaching `letter` during storage of a string that requires *two* chars: 'a' and the terminating nullchar.

Comment: You should also limit the input lengths, with `scanf("%1s", letter); scanf("%19s", word); scanf(" %99[^\n]", sentence);`

Comment: Thanks a lot -WhozCraig, it worked. Thanks – 
Weather Vane , will keep that in mind.

Comment: Don't just "keep it in mind" but *use* it as an essential precaution. Your program is wide open to buffer overflow, escpecially with such a tiny buffer. The user has to "know" that the first word must be a single letter. Write **robust** code.

Comment: You cannot read a string into `letter`, even if you us `%1s`. It can only hold the terminating 0-byte and no other character.

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems

**No width limit**

Never use `scanf()` to read user input into a string lacking a *width* in the format.  The *width* should be less than the array count.

```
char letter[1],word[20],sentence[100];  
// scanf("%s", letter);
// scanf("%s", word);
// scanf(" %[^\n]s", sentence);
scanf("%0s", letter);          // "%0s" not valid.  See below
scanf("%19s", word);
scanf(" %99[^\n]s", sentence); // See below also
```

**Buffer too small for `"%s"`**

`char letter[1]` only big enough for a *null string* `""`.
To read 1 character into a *string*, increase size

```
char letter[2];  
scanf("%1s", letter);
```

**`s` not needed**

`s` serves no point in `" %[^\n]s"`.  Who or whatever text suggested an `s` is a poor source of coding in C practice.

```
// scanf(" %99[^\n]s", sentence);
scanf(" %99[^\n]", sentence);
```

**Check return value**

Test the return value from all `scanf()`.

```
// scanf("%1s", letter);
if (scanf("%1s", letter) != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read into letter");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Note that `scanf("%0s", letter);` is an invalid conversion specifier. I am not even sure what `scanf()` should return for this.

Comment: @chqrlie `"%0s"` is UB as it is not "An optional decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the maximum field width".

Comment: Indeed, and *13 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined*

Comment: Good to see somebody keeping @chux on his toes.... I had never thought of `"%0s"` before, now I have `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The `"%0s"` was just a transitionary code as OP's original `"%s"` lacked a _width_ and a sensible array size.  I was taking OP one step at a time - unfortunately the in-between version of `"%0s"` caught some undue attention.  It is the later `"%1s"` with array size 2 that makes _some_ sense to read a letter and save as a _string_.

Comment: I liked the mind-experiment and the rundown on where it fell off the cliff. Even inquiries part in jest can lead to worthwhile information.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [True, true](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikkg4NobV_w).